# Automatically filling Internet Explorer inputbox - VBA in MSP

Tags: vba, ms-project

Hi I am trying to complete a free text field on a webpage with a string within VBA. My code is as follows.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
Sub Testing()

Dim objIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

Set objIE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

objIE.Navigate "https://someaddress.com/somepath.do"
objIE.Visible = True
Do Until Not objIE.Busy And objIE.ReadyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

objIE.Document.getElementsById("#IO:c0242cf36ff09200b872129e5d3ee445.question_textarea_input cat_item_option").value = "Some String"

End Sub
```

Inspect element on the webpage is as follows

```
<textarea placeholder="Describe in detail the issue you are experiencing." style="overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; resize: none; height: 64px;" rows="5" id="IO:c0242cf36ff09200b872129e5d3ee445" class="question_textarea_input cat_item_option" onchange="if (typeof(variableOnChange) == 'function') variableOnChange('IO:c0242cf36ff09200b872129e5d3ee445')" name="IO:c0242cf36ff09200b872129e5d3ee445" wrap="soft"></textarea>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: why do you have referenced the id and the class Name ? i don't think this works lke that . But any way before you get an answer you should post what Problem you have.... Where do you get an error, or what isn't working like you expect it to work?

Comment: try objIE.Document.getElementById("#IO:c0242cf36ff09200b872129e5d3ee445").value = "Some String" (NOTE not 's' in getElementById)

Comment: The problem I have is a run-time error 424 , Object required. I have adjusted to Steph's suggestion above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this but thank you for your help.

The free text field was within an IFrame

```
Sub Testing()

Dim objIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

Set objIE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

objIE.Navigate "https://someaddress.com/somepath.do"
objIE.Visible = True
Do Until Not objIE.Busy And objIE.ReadyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

Set objIE = obj.Document.getElementID("anIFrame")
objIE.Document.getElementByID("IO:c0242cf36ff09200b872129e5d3ee445").value = "Some String"

End Sub
```